# Hide or show div based on input ID value change?

Tags: javascript

Please see the image in this post to begin with:[image]

Here is what I'm trying to do: Would like to hide/show the box that says "**Additional Information**" on top of the form based on any value greater than 0 put placed in "**Qualified No Admission Attendees**" **ONLY**. The other 2 inputs on this form show not affect this show/hide. The additional information DIV ID # that's I'm trying to hide is: **#lo-EventPreferenceTitle** , so how can I show / hide this div ID based to the value change in the input code below please? If value anything less than 1 **HIDE** the above div, and greater than 1 to show.

```html
<input type="text" class="NetscapeFix CalTicketQuantity form-control" name="tix_quantity" id="tix_quantity2" value="0" size="4" maxlength="4" onchange="calculate(this.form);">
```

Comment: You can create an eventlistener.

Comment: show how please, based on my code

Comment: can u make a stackblitz to work on?

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to change of `tix_quantity2` input value by `keyup` event and if the value of it is less than one hide the `lo-EventPreferenceTitle` div and else show it:

```js
//for default value
if (+$('#tix_quantity2').val() < 1)
    $("#lo-EventPreferenceTitle").hide();


$('#tix_quantity2').keyup(function (e) {
    if (+e.target.value < 1)
        $("#lo-EventPreferenceTitle").hide();
    else
        $("#lo-EventPreferenceTitle").show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div id="lo-EventPreferenceTitle">
        Additional Information
        <textarea></textarea>
    </div>

    <input type="text" class="NetscapeFix CalTicketQuantity form-control" name="tix_quantity" value="0" id="tix_quantity2"  size="4" maxlength="4" >
```

Comment: right now, when it's 0 by default, it's still showing the DIV. only when I change number to 1 for example and back to 0 it then hides. How can I have it hide on 0 by default ?

Comment: @user10366078 Always you have 0 as a default value?

Comment: is there an alternative? not working for me

Comment: @user10366078 If your default value  is always  zero you can set `display:none` for `lo-EventPreferenceTitle` for the first time

Comment: @user10366078 why not working? you have error? are you using jQuery reference?

Comment: @user10366078 I fixed the default value issues. check the answer

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion (pure JS):

```js
var element = document.getElementById('lo-EventPreferenceTitle');

element.style.display = 'none';

tix_quantity2.oninput = () => element.style.display = (tix_quantity2.value > 0) ? 'block' : 'none';
```

```html
<div id="lo-EventPreferenceTitle">
  Additional Information
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>

<input type="text" class="NetscapeFix CalTicketQuantity form-control" name="tix_quantity" value="0" id="tix_quantity2" size="4" maxlength="4">
```